# HTTP Query Parameters With Default String Values

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I can't seem to get a query parameter with a default string value to work.  The route below generates a compile error.  If I remove the `="default value"` for the `type` parameter it compiles fine. Notice the `"page"` parameter with a default int value also works fine.

```
GET   /version   controllers.Application.version(appId:String, buildVersion:Integer, type:String?="default value", page: Int?=2)
```

compile errors:

```
[error] /Users/hyling/Documents/AppConfigServer/conf/routes:8: illegal start of simple expression
[error] GET     /version                    controllers.Application.version(appId:String, buildVersion:Integer, type:String?="default")
[error] /Users/hyling/Documents/AppConfigServer/conf/routes:8: ')' expected but '}' found.
[error] GET     /version                    controllers.Application.version(appId:String, buildVersion:Integer, type:String?="default")
```

Comment: I think you miss the '?'. It should be `type: String ?= "default value"`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  I fixed it in my example.  It doesn't work with ?=.  I was testing if = works and it does.

Comment: Show us the "compile error" to be sure it comes from the `type` parameter

Comment: @c4k the errors go away as soon as I remove ="default value" for the type parameter but I've added the compile erros